# What is the story of the son of Ravana who was a devotee of Narayana?

Tags: vishnu, ramayana, rama, ravana

I recently saw an episode of TV Serial 'Siya Ke Ram' and there it showed that there was a son of Ravana apart from the common ones we know. I am not sure of his name but it was shown that he was a devotee of Narayana (Lord Vishnu) and Ravana earlier kept him in a secluded place and forcing him not to worship Narayana. But later, Ravana offers him that if he fights against Lord Rama then he will be allowed to worship Narayana. Son accepts the offer and goes to fight again Lord Rama. What comes next is yet to be seen in further episodes.

I want to know whether this story is described in Valmiki's Ramayana. If not then where is this story covered. What is the actual story of this incident according to the scriptures.

Comment: As far as Valmiki Ramayana is concerned Ravana's sons are Indrajit, Akshaya, Atikaya, Narantaka and Devantaka. He doesn't have a Narayana Bhakta son, only a brother.

Comment: @Surya there were 2 more that I found on web, Trishira and Prahasta. And the one I am talking about seemed to be Trishira. But I found only following lines about him on web: _He engaged Lord Ram in a fight and hit him with a number of arrows. At this Lord Ram told him that the arrows were nothing but like flowers being showered on his body. Thereafter, a duel ensued, in which Lord Ram killed Trishira_

Comment: I thought Trishiras was killed in Janasthana. And Prahasta was Ravana's Senapati.

Comment: khar Dushan and Trishara were killed in fight in forest before Rama met Sugreev/Hanuman etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Serial is mainly based on Sita book by Devdutt Patnayaik,but with few modifications, Now coming to your questions it can have 2 answers

1. Taranisen -

> Then a warrior entered the battlefield, the kind no monkey or Ram had
>   seen before, He called himself Taranisen and every inch of his body
>   was tattooed with the name of Rama.

Note: This character is given only in **Kritivasa's Ramayana** who is son of vibhison.

2. Virabahu

This character is also similar to above mentioned character , but he is son of Ravana instead and you can find this in **Dandi ramayan** .

Source : Sita an Illustrated Retelling (page number 308 )

Comment: Thanks for your answer. These seem to be most suitable matches. Can you also provide links to the appropriate text in Kriti basa Ramayana and Dandi Ramayana.

Comment: @Aby I am not able to find them in English online so that i can give link , If found will edit in future .

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is authentic. But this story comes from Krittibasi Ramayana.[enter link description here](http://babubanglaramayanretell.blogspot.com/2016/07/virbahu-falls.html)

> > Virbahu was in awe when he saw Rama. He was sure this was other than Vishnu in the guise of a human. He got off his elephant and bowed down
> >     at Rama. Rama was in a dilemma. He would not be able to kill someone
> >     who was devoted to him. Virubahu thought if Rama did not kill him, he
> >     would not achieve his aim. He got up and climbed back on his elephant
> >     and was ready to fight. Rama and Virbahu began their fight.
>
> The sky was covered with arrows. A loud noise was produced with the
>   arrows clashing against each other. When Virbahu invoked the fire
>   weapon, Rama invoked the water weapon. Virbahu then shot an arrow
>   which hit Rama on his chest. Rama, controlling his pain, shot an arrow
>   to cut off the bow of Virbahu. The arrows touched the bow and fell
>   down. Rama then invoked a crescent arrow which then cut off the bow of
>   Virbahu. In his mind, Virbahu was happy. He understood that this time
>   was coming close and the person with whom he was fighting, was none
>   other than Narayan.
>
> Virbahu got another bow and shot some arrows, which Rama cut off.
>   Seeing Rama tired and wounded, Lakshmana shot arrows and cut off the
>   arrows of Virbahu. Virbahu then shot arrows at Lakshmana. The arrows
>   pierced Lakshmana on his chest, and he fell down. Virbahu then aimed a
>   mace towards Lakshmana, which Rama cut off.
>
> Virbahu then said this was not fair, Why was someone interfering in
>   the fight. Why was Ramam cutting off weapons aimed at Lakshmana.
>
> Rama said there was no difference between him and Lakshmana. Virbahu
>   said he was aware of that. All were part of Narayana. Rama was quiet.
>   They resumed fighting.
>
> Rama shot arrows which struck Virbahu. Virbahu fell senseless on his
>   elephant. Seeing his master unconscious, the elephant rose to the sky
>   with its master. Lakshmana asked Rama to kill the demon using the
>   weapon of Brahma. Rama said that would not be fair. After all Virbahu
>   was a noble learned person.
>
> Virbahu regained his senses. Sugriva said he had heard that Virbahu's
>   life was tied to the elephant. If the elephant died, Virbahu would
>   also die. Saying this, Sugriva rose to the sky. Sugriva hurled a big
>   boulder at the elephant. The animal caught the boulder in its tusks
>   and crushed it. Sugriva then hurled a tree which struck the elephant
>   on its head and broke. The elephant then grabbed Sugriva in its trunk
>   and threw him aside.
>
> Virbahu then asked Rama to come and fight and not let any second
>   person interfere.
>
> Rama said You talk of fairness. Your aunt, Surpanakha, a widow, came
>   to entice me and Lakshmana and got her ears and nose cut. That was her
>   character. Your father forcibly abducted my wife. He also pushed out
>   his elder brother, Kubera, from Lanka, and took over the kingdom.
>
> Saying this, the fight between Rama and Virbahu resumed, with one
>   cutting off the arrows of the other. Rama was hurt by an arrow and he
>   fell down. Seeing this, Vibhishana picked up a bow and started
>   fighting in place of Rama.
>
> Virbahu said Our dynasty is blessed to have a person like you, so
>   devoted to Vishnu.
>
> Rama regained composure and the fight started again.
>
> Seeing no alternative, Virbahu invoked the weapon he had got from
>   Brahma and used that. Rama was unable to repel that. Pavan then came
>   and told Rama to use the weapon he had got from the sage Sarabhanga.
>   Rama fetched that weapon and released it. The arrow, cut off the arrow
>   released by Virbahu and then it went and cut off the head of the
>   elephant.
>
> Virbahu jumped off the elephant. Rama cut off the bow of Virbahu.
>   Virbahu then asked Rama to use the weapon of Vishnu and make an end of
>   him. Rama, Rama was reluctant but then thought, if Vibahu did not die,
>   Ravana would not get killed. So, he decided to use the weapon.
>
> The weapon went and cut off the head of Virbahu. The cut head was
>   chanting the name of Rama. Vibhishana got the cut head to Rama. With
>   Rama's touch, Virbahu was released from the earthly bounds.
>
> Rama asked Vibhishana how many such warriors were there in Lanka. Vibhishana said now only Ravana and Indrajit were left.